# Getting this BackEnd error : 'TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object as I attempt to derive age for DOB.'

Tags: python, django, typeerror

I am attempting to derive age from date of birth, and I keep getting this error :

`match = date_re.match(value), TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

These are the imports :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import now
from Self import settings
```

This is the class creation

```
class Identity_unique(models.Model):

    NIS_Identity = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now =True)
    First_Name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default =0)
    Last_Name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default=now)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(max_length=8, default=0)
    patient_age = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):

        Is_present = date.today()
        patient_age = Is_present.year - date_of_birth.year

        if Is_present.month < date_of_birth.month or Is_present.month == date_of_birth.month and Is_present.day < date_of_birth.day:
            patient_age -= 1

        return self.patient_age

    Contact = models.IntegerField()
```

This is the ModelForm :

```
from django import forms 
from .models import Identity_unique


class Identity_form(forms.ModelForm):

    NIS_Identity = forms.IntegerField()
    First_Name = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)
    Last_Name = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField()
    patient_age = forms.IntegerField()
    Contact = forms.CharField()


    class Meta:

        model = Identity_unique

        fields = ('NIS_Identity','First_Name', 'Last_Name', 'date_of_birth', 'patient_age', 'Contact', )
```

I keep getting the `match = date_re.match(value), TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object` error each time I try to run the `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands

Here is an image of the complete error :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I stumble upon a similar problem recently. So I decided to post a solution.In my case I had trouble migrating existing migration files to postgres database.

I did two things to resolve this.Others might try one or the other or both
Solution:

1. **delete migrations files** in the app which is showing error except `__init__.py` file.In this case files are inside `home/migrations/` folder
2. **convert the output value to string:** I was generating dropdown list with years 
   like [(2020,2020)(2019,2019)...] I converted it to make the second item in tuple an string like [(2020,"2020")(2019,"2019")...]

Don't edit migration files just delete files and use makemigrations command to recreate the new migration files.